# 6TB hard drive unrecognized by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I have a PC with an ASROCK FM2A88M EXTREME4+ motherboard, and a working OS on a 128GB SSD. 
I recently purchased a Western Digital Red (NAS) 6TB hard drive, and promptly tried hooking it up for added storage. 
The drive made some odd whirring and buzzing sounds repeatedly (looping), and then went silent.

The drive wasn't detected by the BIOS, which I made sure to update after it didn't recognize it, after which it still wasn't detected. I've since had the drive replaced with a new one, and now the same thing is happening again. I've tried different SATA cables, yet the BIOS detects nothing, even with different AHCI/IDE settings.

What could I be missing? Why would the motherboard not detect the drive?

*EDIT 2018-02:*
Just an update since this has been getting some views: It seems as though the first 2 drives were simply DOA. Third drive was indeed the charm, although I will definitely think twice before ordering another like it in the future.

Comment: You might need this: http://www.asrock.com/feature/3tb/ but I'm just taking a stab in dark here.

Comment: "The drive made some odd whirring and buzzing sounds repeatedly (looping), and then went silent." Are you sure the drive is good, it is not unheard of, although it is very rare, to get a bad out of box drive. Generally BIOS/UEFI will always recognize a drive, but not always it's proper capacity, which is where the previous commenter's link comes into play. As long as you have the latest BIOS/UEFI on the board, there is no reason it shouldn't be recognized.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. All other issues similar to mine seem to be capacity issues - mine isn't recognized at all. And this is the second one that isn't working out of the box. I saw someone with a similar failing issue somewhere online, I'm not sure if it was this guy: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=63716&start=30

Comment: This looks pretty unfortunate! :( I'd suggest you attempt to connect to another computer and see how it will get detected there. If the problem persists, get in touch with our [Customer Support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=XyJ5AW). I'd also use @CBHacking's advice and troubleshoot the drive by unplugging other SATA devices from your mobo. Keep us posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the BIOS can't see the drive at all, you probably have a bad drive or a bad connection. Try disconnecting your current boot drive (SSD), both power and data cables, without disconnecting the cables on the motherboard/power supply side (obviously, do this with the computer shut down and the power disconnected). Then, try connecting the new drive using the same cables and booting up. See if the BIOS can detect the drive at all (and also if the drive spins up correctly). If the drive doesn't even spin up, it's almost certainly defective and should be returned. Otherwise, see if the BIOS is aware that the drive is there at all. If your computer normally does a fast/silent POST (Power On Self Test), turn that option off in the BIOS; it should enumerate connected SATA devices and you should be able to see if it detects the drive then.

Other ways to detect a bad drive would be to use a computer and cable that you know supports large drives and seeing if the new drive is detected there, or using SATA-to-USB adapter (such as an external drive housing) with a booted computer and seeing if the computer detects the drive over USB. If you don't have such things handy, though, it's probably easier to just take the drive to a computer store. Pretty much any store will be able to test it for you quickly.

If the BIOS can see that the drive exists but can't read it, you may have a bad drive but you also may just have an old BIOS that doesn't understand GPT (GUID Partition Table) drives. GPT replaces the old MBR (Master Boot Record) disk format, because MBR only supports up to 2TB. Any drive more than 2TB in size will be a GPT drive. You could convert the drive from GPT to the legacy format, but you'd be wasting 2/3 of your drive, unable to address it at all.

Legacy IBM-compatible BIOS only supported MBR drives. Most motherboards sold in the last few years either use (U)EFI - the (Unified) Extensible Firmware Interface - instead of the legacy BIOS firmware, or at least have GPT support added into the BIOS (sometimes called an "enhanced" or "hybrid" BIOS).